# Can "tightrope" be used as a verb?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Can tightrope be used as a verb? Or is it strictly a noun?

Example from my work in progress:

> As most young children do, I acted upon the irresistible urge to **tightrope**, on top of the cobblestone.

If so, is 'tightrope' the correct spelling for the verb form or should it be hyphenated, like 'tight-rope'.

Comment: Practically any noun can be "verbed" these days. However, do so only when the meaning is obvious in the context with no ambiguity. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

Tightrope is a noun. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tightrope

The associated verb phrase is "to tightrope walk."

Comment: Sure, but see also my comment at OP.

Comment: @ Kris, Very true about nouns being "verbed" and of course in a creative work, authors may do what they like to try to convey the meaning and emotion of what they're going for. Still, it would be a relatively new/unusual coinage.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it can.  See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrSwC2-RBnk) at 1:15. Precious few nouns can't be verbed. I've seen it noted that "faith" is one of them. Fascinating, given that "trust" is a common verb.

Comment: *Some problems you just have to faith straight on.* :P